# JSON object enityt that has child of same object with restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm not sure I fully understand RestKit anymore. How can I create relationships with itself while still maintaining other relationships?

My JSON is structured like this:

```
{
    "review" : {
        "id" : "123",
        "someotherkey" : "blah",
        "responses" : [
            {
                "id" : "345",
                "text" : "no"
            },
            {
                "id" : "346",
                "text" : "no"
            }
        ],
        "childReviews" : [
            {
                "id" : "124",
                "someotherkey" : "blsdah",
                "responses" : [
                    {
                        "id" : "347",
                        "text" : "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "348",
                        "text" : "no"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "125",
                "someotherkey" : "blasdh",
                "responses" : [
                    {
                        "id" : "355",
                        "text" : "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "326",
                        "text" : "no"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So for my RestKit I'm mapping I have something like this:

```
 [reviewMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"childReviews" mapping:reviewMapping];
 [reviewMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"responses" mapping:responsesMapping];
```

Which worked fine when childReview objects didn't contain the key "responses" but now that I've added it it's breaking and giving me this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
 reason:'[<Review 0x104f1260> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity
 Review is not key value coding-compliant for the key "responses".'
```

I'm not sure I fully understand RestKit anymore. How can I create relationships with itself while still maintaining other relationships?

Comment: Review is a subclass of NSManagedObject? Does it have a "responses" attribute?

Comment: responses is a relationship, but yes Review is a NSManagedObject